# How to hide form field while reusing same form

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using the following form to save user information.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<sf:form action="someAction"method="post" commandName="backingBean">
    <sf:input type="hidden" name="userId" path="userId" />
    <sf:input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" path="username"  />
    <sf:input placeholder="Password" path="password" type="password" name="password" />
    <sf:input placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" path="email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</sf:form>
```

When an user want to edit their information I am sending them the same form using hidden userId. But this time I wish  not show password filed in the form. How do I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with an `<c:choose><c:when..` that tests a condition and does what you want: "not show password filed in the form"

Comment: i have a domain class and that class have some validation. if i use <c:choose> then the field is hide but when i submit the form some validation message shows and password field shown with some message like "password should contain 5 characters".this message i set some properties file to show validation error message.How do i handle this?

Comment: then probably you have to change class defining the form to a class where password field is optional or does not exist at all and then copy the properties to the domain object on successful validation